# Combine values in two columns together based specific conditions in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data that looks like the following:

```
moo <- data.frame(Farm = c("A","B",NA,NA,"A","B"), 
                  Barn_Yard = c("A","A",NA,"A",NA,"B"), 
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
print(moo)
Farm Barn_Yard
 A         A
 B         A
<NA>      <NA>
<NA>       A
 A       <NA>
 B         B
```

I am attempting to combine the columns into one variable where if they are the same the results yields what is found in both columns, if both have data the result is what is in the `Farm` column, if both are `<NA>` the result is `<NA>`, and if one has a value and the other doesn't the result is the value present in the column that has the value.  Thus, in this instance the result would be:

```
oink <- data.frame(Animal_House = c("A","B",NA,"A","A","B"), 
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

print(oink)
Animal_House
        A
        B
     <NA>
        A
        A
        B
```

I have tried the `unite` function from `tidyr` but it doesn't give me exactly what I want.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dplyr::coalesce` does exactly that, substituting any `NA` values in the first vector with the value from the second:

```r
library(dplyr)

moo <- data.frame(Farm = c("A","B",NA,NA,"A","B"), 
                  Barn_Yard = c("A","A",NA,"A",NA,"B"), 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

oink <- moo %>% mutate(Animal_House = coalesce(Farm, Barn_Yard))

oink
#>   Farm Barn_Yard Animal_House
#> 1    A         A            A
#> 2    B         A            B
#> 3 <NA>      <NA>         <NA>
#> 4 <NA>         A            A
#> 5    A      <NA>            A
#> 6    B         B            B
```

If you want to discard the original columns, use `transmute` instead of `mutate`.

Answer (score 0):

A less succinct option is to use a couple `ifelse()` statements, but this could be useful if you wish to introduce another condition or column into the mix.

```
moo <- data.frame(Farm = c("A","B",NA,NA,"A","B"), 
                  Barn_Yard = c("A","A",NA,"A",NA,"B"), 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

moo$Animal_House = with(moo,ifelse(is.na(Farm) & is.na(Barn_Yard),NA,
                                   ifelse(!is.na(Barn_Yard) & is.na(Farm),Barn_Yard,
                                          Farm)))
```